# MINE VS MY in the sentence called: HERE IS MINE/MY 100 DAYS

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say

> HERE IS MINE(break)100 DAYS OF
> OR
> HERE IS MY(break) 100 DAYS OF

I would really like to go with "MINE" but  I need to know if its acceptable/correct.

Comment: Hi, Skymira!  What research did you do before posting?  If you do a web search for "my or mine" you will find a lot of information.

Comment: What does "(break) mean? 100 days of what???

Comment: Yeah context is important here. I can easily construct something that would be correct. "Thank you for sharing your least favorite movie. Here is mine: '100 Days of Summer.'"

Answer (score 2):

Centuries ago you could have used ***mine*** instead of ***my*** - Shakespeare used both in the same sentence without batting an eyelid[...

> [***Mine** honor is **my** life;*](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/943144-mine-honor-is-my-life-both-grow-in-one-take) *both grow in one.*
> *Take honor from me, and my life is done.*

But you can't do that now. These days, it would have to be modeled after [***My** word is **my** bond.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=My%20word%20is%20my%20bond&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

---

It's *This is **mine** and that's **yours*** when the possessive pronouns are ***used as nouns***. When they're ***"adjectival" determiners modifying nouns*** it's *This is **my** answer to **your** question*.

Comment: Weren't 'mine' and 'thine' permitted in place of 'my' and 'thy' only when the following sound was a vowel - so 'mine honour' (the 'h' was sillent) but not 'mine dog'? And did Old Bill spell 'honor' that way?

Comment: The AmE spelling just came from Goodreads, when I cut&pasted the text and the link. I didn't know about the "before a vowel" business, but I see that someone else says [*In archaic English, they **tend** to use 'mine' as an adjective (or rather a determiner) before nouns that started with a vowel.*](https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/189/is-mine-a-pronoun-or-an-adjective) I very much doubt that tendency was anywhere near a syntactic rule, though.

Comment: *A Midsummer Nights Dream* has *How came her eyes so bright? Not with salt tears:
If so, **my eyes** are oftener wash'd than hers.*

Comment: That theory would certainly echo that of 'an hotel' etc. [hmmm… I've upvoted the answer whilst vtc-ing the question… can't win 'em all, I guess;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yes, a trend, or permissible option, and not a rule.

Answer (score 0):

As a pronoun, use "mine", as a determiner of a noun phrase, use "my".

You have a determiner, so you must use "my 100 days of...."

As an aside, don't use all capital letters unless you mean that something is shouted.